# Calling a C function with a b"..." string parameter

Tags: python, ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc/so/6")
libc.printf(b"Hello world")
```

I was studying the library `ctypes` in Python. In above `printf` function why do we use `b` before `"Hello world"`?

Comment: The "b" indicates a byte-string. `printf` expects a string of (single, ASCII) bytes, not unicode points (which make up the default strings, i.e., non-"b" strings, in Python).

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `b"..."` notation represents a byte string.  Byte strings are immutable are appropriate for passing to `const char *` C function parameters, or `char *` if the function is known not to write to the string.  Use `ctypes.create_string_buffer()` if you need a writeable buffer.